# Как вынести создание ретрофита в отдельный класс?

Tags: java, android

Как вынести создание ретрофита в отдельный класс?

Чтобы я мог его в разных местах инициализировать?

Comment: А Вы уверены что Вам нужно `его в разных местах инициализировать`? Что Вы подразумеваете под инициализацией? Может Вы просто хотите использовать **один и тот же** инстанс Ретрофита в разных частях программы? Если да, то зачем?

Comment: @post_zeew, да я хочу использовать один и тот же инстанс Ретрофита в разных частях программы?

Answer (score 2):

Создайте singleton в application например. Или можно использовать dagger2

Answer (score 0):

public class PhpClient {

```
private static IPhpApi API;

public static IPhpApi getApi() {
    if (API == null) setupClient();
    return API;
}

private static void setupClient() {

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new HttpLoggerInterceptor()).build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Config.BASE_SCRIPT_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    API = retrofit.create(IPhpApi.class);
}
```

}